# meteorjs global function for client

Tags: javascript, meteor

i try to define a validation function for my meteor app. I have to validate the post-data on client side but als oon server side to prevent the manipulation.

because of this i defined the function in the dir **myApp/lib/validation/**

I added a submit event on my form and call  a meteorjs methode. In this methode i call my validation function.

Validation function in myApp/lib/validation/:

```
function Validation (post) {
    this.validate = function () {
        console.log(post)
        return true;
    };
};
```

Submit Event in myApp/client/manager/:

```
Template.UserRegisterForm.events({
    'submit form' : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = {test : 'success'};
        Meteor.call('userRegisterFormPost', post, function(error, postdata) {
        });
    }
});
```

Methode in myApp/lib/methodes/:

```
Meteor.methods({
  userRegisterFormPost : function(attr) {
    var validate = new Validation(attr);    

  }
});
```

This does **not** work, because "Validation is not defined". Maybe i understood the architecture of meteorjs not in the right way so maybe you can tell me how to solve this simple step i want to do ?

Answer (score 5):

Meteor automatically wraps files in IIFEs, so for a variable/function to be shared between files it needs to be declared on the global scope. Try this:

```
Validation = function (post) {
    this.validate = function () {
        console.log(post)
        return true;
    };
};
```

One way to make this more explicit is to wrap your files in your own IIFE, passing in a global reference. For example:

```
(function(global) {
    function Validation (post) {}

    Validation.prototype.validate = function () {
        console.log(post)
        return true;
    };

    global.Validation = Validation;
})(this);
```

Another similar pattern that does the same thing would be:

```
this.Validation = (function() {
    function Validation (post) {}

    Validation.prototype.validate = function () {
        console.log(post)
        return true;
    };

    return Validation;
})();
```

Comment: simple and understandable. Thanks for the fast answer. I will note it in the future. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is it possible if i want to do , Template.temp_name.helpers({
    helper : Validation('parameter');
});